# can i save share preference file userwise in android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to save my preference file based on user.my app based on multi user login, if i used same device for login and logout then user1 preferences conflict with user2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a SharedPreferences instance for a filename using [Context.getSharedPreferences(String, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)). Just use different filenames for different users.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multiple preference files using `context.getSharedPreferences("UNIQUE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`.

In your case, "UNIQUE KEY" can be user's id for example.